# Print an array using a method that has a loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

I need to print an array using a loop inside a method. My code works but only for one number. I need to print the array with x increasing by 1 and y increasing by 5.
the code should look like this

```
feet  meters |  meters    feet 
1.0  0.305   |  20.0    65.574
2.0  0.610   |  25.0    81.967
...    
9.0  2.745   |  60.0    196.721
10.0  3.050  |  65.0    213.115
```

this is my code

```
    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 20.0;

    double k = footToMeter(x);//gets footToMeter
    double m = meterToFoot(y);
    System.out.print("Feet\tMeters\t|   Meters\tFeet");
    System.out.printf("\n%.1f\t%.3f\t|   %.1f\t%.3f",x,k,y,m);
}//close main

public static double footToMeter(double foot) {
    double meter = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        meter = 0.305 * foot;
    }
    foot++;
    return meter;  
}//close footToMeter

public static double meterToFoot(double meter) {
    double foot = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<65; i++) {
        foot = 3.279 * meter;
    }
    meter++; 
    return foot;
}//close meterToFoot
```

Comment: Are you facing any problems? if yes, then what?

Comment: Please review your code and check if the loops are at the right place.

Comment: the problem is that it only prints out for only the first set instead of the whole array

Comment: You never change the values of `x` and `y`. When you pass them in to the methods, you are just passing in their values, so incrementing the values in those methods doesn't change the values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: do i increment x and y in the main code?

Comment: You need to rethink your design of this program. A method should do one thing. So, if you have a method named `meterToFoot`, then I would assume that method would just convert a value in meters into feet, and return it. See Stefan's answer for a good example of how to design it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in my comment to your answer, please check if the loops are located at the right place.

From your problem description and code I would try a solution like this:

```
...
double x = 1.0;
double y = 20.0;
double k;
double m;

System.out.print("Feet\tMeters\t|   Meters\tFeet"); 
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  k = footToMeter(x);
  m = meterToFoot(y);

  System.out.printf("\n%.1f\t%.3f\t|   %.1f\t%.3f",x,k,y,m);
  x = x+1;
  y = y+5;
 }
}

public static double footToMeter(double foot) {
 return 0.305 * foot;
}

public static double meterToFoot(double meter) {
 return 3.279 * meter;
}
```

Comment: yes my loop was in the wrong place. i thought it had to be in the method for it to work. thanks a lot